# Сравнение двух массива на точное вхождение

Tags: php, массивы

Как можно проверить на точное совпадение двух массивов ключа и значения к примеру -  масиив1 по ключу будет сравнивается по значению масиив2

Comment: `$result = array_intersect_key($array_one, array_flip($array_two));`

Comment: @Let'ssayPie в след.раз не стесняйтесь оставлять как ответ ;)

Comment: @Manitikyl, да там особо расписывать нечего было) только если с примерами)

Comment: @Manitikyl, все же написал ответ, мало ли кого-нибудь заинтересует, хд)

Answer (score 1):

Для вычисления схождения массивов в PHP используются функции **array_intersectXXX**. Для расхождения — **array_diffXXX**. На выходе массивы, по которым вы можете определить схождение/расхождение. Вам придётся залезть в документацию, чтобы подобрать нужный вариант для своей задачи. :)

Answer (score 1):

Имеем два массива:

```
$array_one = array('a' => 123, 'b' => 213, 'c' => 321); 
$array_two = array('b', 'c');
```

Делаем простой ключевой фильтр:

```
$result = array_intersect_key($array_one, array_flip($array_two));
print_r($result);
```

Вы выходе получаем:

```
Array 
( 
    [b] => 213 
    [c] => 321 
)
```